# Split contexts between http and https

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

We want to migrate our web application from http to https.
That in itself would be simple. However, we have one problem.

We deploy three contexts: main.war, reporting.war and generator.war

Due to some legacy code elswhere in our application, access to generator has to stay http while main and reporting only allow https.

I tried modifying the server.xml by adding an additional "Service" to the server and put contexs "main" and "reporting" into the one with https and "generator" in the http service.

The problem is that all contexts now accept both http and https and I don't have an idea why.

Could you help me to understand and fix this?
Thank You!

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
   <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
   <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
   <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
   <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
   <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
   <GlobalNamingResources>
     <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
               type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
               description="User database that can be updated and saved"
               factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
               pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
   </GlobalNamingResources>

   <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector
        protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
        port="443" maxThreads="200"
        scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
        keystoreFile="file:///C:/tomcat/testkey.keyfile" keystorePass="testpassword"
        clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
     <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
     <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
       <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
         <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
       </Realm>
       <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
             unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">    
         <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
                pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
        <Context docBase="main" path="/main" reloadable="true" source="main"/>
        <Context docBase="reporting" path="/reporting" reloadable="true" source="reporting"/>
       </Host>
     </Engine>
   </Service>

  <Service name="CatalinaGenerator">
     <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
                port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                connectionTimeout="20000" />
     <Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
     <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
       <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
         <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
       </Realm>
       <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
         <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"      prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"/>
         <Context docBase="generator" path="/generator" reloadable="true" source="generator"/>
       </Host>
     </Engine>
   </Service>

 </Server>
```

Comment: Do you have checked the error logs? Thats because you have declared <Connector port="8009" doubled.

Comment: Well spotted, yes, there have some warnings because of that. I removed the second port="8009" line.

The behaviour stays the same.
The logs contain only INFO lines except for these:
   `SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent Creation of the naming context failed: javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: Context is read only`

   `WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'main' did not find a matching property.`

Answer (score 0):

For such setups I personally added an apache http in front of a tomcat and handle such things with mod_proxy.